# Metric space and continuity proof.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have this proposition.

Let X,Y be a metric spaces and let $f:X \to Y$ be a map.
Then f is continuous if and only if $f^{-1} (V)$ is closed in X whenever V is closed in Y.

How would you go about proving this?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511601/4280 (which has no accepter answer...., so I cannot vote for closing as duplicate )

Comment: Do you know the result with "open" instead of "closed"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It would not need an accepted answer, an answer with positive score suffices.